# Write list of data frames to CSVs in R

Tags: r, list, variables, apply

I have a named list of data frames and want to write each data frame out to a CSV, using the data frame name as the filename. How can I modify my function to do that? The function below gives me the entire data frame in the file name instead of the name of the data frame.

```
a <- data.frame('col1' = c(1,2,3))
b <- data.frame('col1' = c(3,4,5))
mylist <- list(a,b)
names(mylist) <- c('a', 'b')
lapply(mylist, function(x) write.csv(x, file = paste0(x, '.csv')))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With base R you can do.

```
lapply(names(mylist), function(x) {write.csv(mylist[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".csv"))})
```

Or you can use the shortcut command iwalk from the tidyverse library purrr.

```
iwalk(mylist, function(x, y) {write.csv(x, file = paste0(y, ".csv"))})

## Or this alternative syntax.

iwalk(mylist, ~write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

Comment: great answer - so many red herrings elsewhere using over complex code.